# How to give Fixed wait in playwright With out any condition Like we had in cypress : Cy.wait(600)

Tags: automation, cypress, playwright, playwright-test

How to give Fixed(Implicit Wait) wait  in playwright
With out any condition

Like we had in cypress :

Cy.wait(600);

Thank You

Like we had in cypress :

Cy.wait(600);

Comment: Always have a conditional wait until the specific condition either fulfills or timeout.

Answer (score 13):

To give a fixed wait in Playwright without using any conditions, you can use the page.waitForTimeout method. This method will pause the script for a specified amount of time before continuing.

```
await page.waitForTimeout(2000); // waits for 2 seconds
```

You can also use the page.waitForFunction method with a function that returns true after a certain amount of time. For example:

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => {
  const now = Date.now();
  return now - start > 2000;
});
```

This will wait for 2 seconds before returning true.

Note that these methods should be used sparingly as they can cause delays in the script execution. It is generally better to use specific conditions to determine when to continue, such as waiting for a specific element to be present or for a page to load.

Comment: Using Hard- coded waits is a bad practice not only in Playwright but in general in any UI test automation as well.

Answer (score 5):

#### Avoid using hard waits with [playwright](https://playwright.dev/)(or with any UI test automation library)!

**Issue with Hard waits:**

> Hard waits do only one thing - they simply wait for specified time
> without considering any application actual response time which is very
> rigid approach.

See the below example:

```
await page.waitForTimeout(5000); // hard wait for 5000ms
```

This will wait for 5 seconds regardless of actual response time which may be less or more than 5 seconds which is bad in both cases as in first case it has to wait unnecessary for longer time where object is already loaded and in second scenario it will fail after waiting unnecessary for 5 seconds if object is not going to load at all in failing scenario.

#### Recommended Approach

#### Wait for expected change in the page

```
// For example a specific element is visible after login
await expect(page.getByText('Welcome')).toBeVisible();
```

###### In-built waits

Playwright has [in-built waiting](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) mechanism on [navigation](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations) and [page interactions](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability). As they are part of playwright itself , it is better to use them and customize it  if required.

###### Explicit waits

There is another way to handle waits explicitly only in scenarios where auto-waiting is not a sufficient or efficient approach to handle depending on specific scenarios but in general it should be avoided if auto-waiting is enough for the requirement.

**Waiting for page navigations and API responses**

1)[page.waitForNavigation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation) to wait until a page navigation (new URL or page reload) has completed.

2)page.[waitForLoadState](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-load-state) This waits until the required load state has been achieved.

3)[page.waitForURL](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url) This waits until a navigation to the target URL.

4)[page.waitForResponse](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response) waits till the response from the given API is received.

**Wait for element**

In lazy-loaded pages, it can be useful to wait until an element is visible with locator.waitFor(). Alternatively, page interactions like page.click() auto-wait for elements.

```
// Navigate and wait for element
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.getByText('Example Domain').waitFor();

// Navigate and click element
// Click will auto-wait for the element
await page.goto('https://example.com');
await page.getByText('Example Domain').click();
```

**Waiting on page events**

We can also directly wait on page events using [page.waitForEvent](https://playwright.dev/docs/events).

**Customized Wait Function**

At last we can also write (if really needed) customized wait functions using [WaitForFunction](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-function) for very specific scenarios or specific applications controls.

Comment: await page.waitFor(5000); does not exist

Comment: @vlatko606  Thank you for letting me know , I apologize for the mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 sec timeout

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
```